# Buy 2 of same item (no need to color match) and Get 1 of them 50% Off

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I have a specific requirement.

Buy 2 of same item (no need to color match) and Get 1 of them 50% Off.

**Case 1 :-**
Here the main thing is that if there are two simple products
Red and Green of an configurable product and each has qty 1 in the
cart then 50% discount of any one of the item should be given to the
customer. So let say  
Red -> $50    qty 1 
Green -> $50  qty 1
============
SubTotal = $100 
Discount    = $25 
Grand Total = $75

**Case 2:-** The next case is that if there is just a simple product and
if it has 2 qtys in the cart then also 50% of the price should be
deducted from the cart.

Red -> $50 (qty 2)
============ 
SubTotal = $100
Discount = $25
Grand Total = $75

**case 3 :-** is the combination of case 1 and case 2 . It should work
even if both the above cases are there in cart.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a custom solution here really.  Case 2 can be handled by tiered pricing, but the other 2 can't be handled out of the box - need a developer to build the functionality for you.

Might be able to work something to approximate behaviour with custom options but it wouldn't be a complete solution.

Comment: You are correct I have created the rule for the case 2 but I need solution for case 3. :)